# How should a browser interact with a local device?

Tags: architecture, cross-browser, cross-platform

**How should this be implemented?**

1. User has a USB device ("doorbell") attached to their machine.
2. User goes to the client's web page and clicks a link.
3. A notification appears "Please press the doorbell."
4. User presses doorbell, website is notified.

The "doorbell" is actually a complex device with its own SDK, and it's sending back a big blob of data. The device manufacturer provides SDKs for both Windows and OSX. I can write native code for either platform to interact with the device at the OS level.

### Plan A

1. `LocalWatchdog` process runs on the user's machine.
2. Browser plugin catches the webpage event
3. Browser plugin does **something** (using NPAPI?) to signal `LocalWatchdog`
4. `LocalWatchdog` pops the notification & gets the doorbell-press event
5. `LocalWatchdog` does **something** to tell the plugin that the doorbell has been pressed.
6. The plugin tells the website.

### Plan B

1. The website downloads a Java applet which runs locally on the user's machine.
2. The applet pops the notification.
3. The applet does **something** to catch the doorbell-press event.
4. The applet tells the website the doorbell has been pressed.

Other plans welcomed, but in any case, what are the **somethings**?

- Any language is acceptable.
- Non-trivial installation process is acceptable.
- Must run on OSX and Windows. If I have to write it twice, I will.
- Must run with Chrome, Firefox, and IE. If I have to write it three times, I will.

Comment: I'm curious: even with a signed Java applet can you do native code execution?

Comment: Yes, through JNI. But now Google is pushing the Chrome Native Client approach instead.

Comment: Meh Native Client. Interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a local process, I'd say:

1. Run a local webserver that talks to the hardware and uses an appropriate cross-domain XML file.
2. Use an Ajax call to ask speak to it from the browser and ask for the button press
3. When the local webserver gets the request, hit the hardware with an appropriate message (I'm assume its some USB HID-type thing).
4. Signal the user in the browser, then open a long-polling request again to the local webserver and wait for a response.
5. If the user hits the button, return the data to the browser request.
6. Profit (we hope).

Comment: So when the page asks for `http://localhost:9999/mydevice`, the local process handles it? Hm, definitely maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to be coupled at all?

User on browser clicks a link.  This queues an event on a back-end system.

Independently, LocalWatchdog process on host polls the back-end via a REST API or similar periodically (every minute?)  If there is a pending operation, it acknowledges this (and deletes it from the server) and then pops up the dialog to "press the doorbell button".

Any solution where the browser and the hardware have to interact within the confines of the user's machine is going to be a very frustrating exercise, especially with that list of browsers to support.

Comment: So if 10,000 users have the doorbell, my host is being polled 10,000 times a minute, 24/7? (Have I misunderstood?)

Comment: The interval is up to you.  But I see your point.  Femi's idea isn't a bad one.